# Are there errors in the description of this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, zener

### Background

The circuit describes the operation of a variable voltage power supply. In the description below the circuit diagram there are errors. Read through the description and note down any errors. Just describe the error and say why you think it is an error.

Don't need to go into any detail just say way you think the description is incorrect or could be improved.

[image: Circuit]

[image: Description 1]

[image: Description 2]

### My Answer

This is what I have come up with so far, please let me know if you can see any other errors:

Point 1 - How can you get 28V from the The 20V output transfer.

Point 2 - Transistor is not ideal, will not be constant current.

Point 3  - The voltage does not remain constant over very wide range 
           of temperature with Zener  diode.  When Zener break down, 
           voltage decreases as the temperature increases.

Point 16 – R10 is a typo, it should be R6

### New Points

Point 16 – If the current is 1A, the Voltage across R6 is 0.47V and this is not enough to turn on the transistor as stated

Point 10 – Says that the load drawing less current will cause an increase in voltage however, according to ohms law this is not true and it would cause an decrease in voltage

Comment: Q1 - 20V is an RMS value thus the peak value is 28V. Q2-but this circuit is a constant current source. Q3 - I do not remember exact value but the Zener diode with breakdown voltage around 5V will have o 0 or positive temperature coefficient.   Point16 ??

Comment: This looks like homework or an exam question. This isn't Chegg; we don't hand out homework answers here. You need to explain your thinking and show your work if you want help.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I literally gave my answers but was just wondering if there was anything I missed...

Comment: @G36 Sorry I forgot to add the other points, just added them!

Comment: You are asking us to evaluate all of the ones that you might have missed. Instead, you should go through all of the other points and explain why you think they are **correct**. Show us your reasoning for that.

Comment: Point 16 – If the current is 1A, the Voltage across R6 is 0.47V and this is not enough to turn on the transistor as stated.

Comment: Point 10 – Says that the load drawing less current will cause an increase in voltage however, according to ohms law this is not true and it would cause an decrease in voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok Thank you for your input, I have added two points that i think are wrong please let me know if i am correct

Comment: For me Point 10 looks good. And you are wrong.